# unknown command "images" for "docker"

Tags: image, docker, containers

I've installed docker in windows 10 successfully.
I can run `docker version` and see this result

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.4
 Version:           20.10.0
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        7287ab3
 Built:             Tue Dec  8 18:55:31 2020
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           myacicontext
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.0
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       eeddea2
  Built:            Tue Dec  8 19:07:44 2020
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

but when I run `$ docker images` I receive this error

```
unknown command "images" for "docker"
```

Comment: `docker image ls` maybe?

Comment: no unfortunately,
I've tried it before

Comment: Just a wild guess; do you have the docker path in your Windows Path environment variable?

Comment: what is the output of `docker --help`? It should list all the command which includes `images` to List images.

Comment: Yes I have @j. Scott Elblein

Comment: No, I don't see 'images' and even 'build'

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not in the right context.

From your logs I can see that you're in the "acicontext" where the `$ docker images` command is not available. I had the same issue when I tried to deploy a container to Azure.

To resolve this, first, run the command `$ docker context list` in Powershell. You should be seeing a list of contexts and the one that you're on has a star right next to its name like so :

[image: powershell with the docker context list command running]

If you want to be able to use the `$ docker images` command you have to go inside the right context, which in this example is "default". To do so, run `$ docker context use default`

Then run `$ docker images` again, it should be working.

[image: whole process in image]

You can read more about Docker context here https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I had to uninstall and reinstall, wich